Подключение CSS файла к редактору VS code
не получается подключить CSS файл к HTML файлу в редакторе VS code.


body {
  font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100pt;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 100pt;
  text-align: justify;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Йокогама: суши-бар</title>
  <link href="CSS/Dronov_2.1 style.css" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Суши-бар <em>Йокогама</em></h1>
  <!--Вывести этот заголовок по центру страницы-->
  <p>
    <img src="images/sushi.jpg" title="суши" width="500" alt="здесь лежит картинка суши" />
  </p>
  <p>У нас вы найдете: суши, ролы, соусы, <strong>горячие блюда.</strong></p>
  <p>
    Также - безалкогольные напитки.
    <img src="images/drink.jpg" title="напитки" width="50" alt="здесь лежит картинка напитков" />
  </p>
  <p>Подаваемые напитки: чай, кофе, мате.</p>
  <p>Ждем Вас!</p>
  <address>Наш адрес: ул. Зеленая, 17</address>
</body>

</html>




Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Почитай про относительные и абсолютные пути.

Спасибо большое
